# Conectar a Base de Datos, según parámetro URL

Tags: base-de-datos, url, parametros

intento conectar a una DB según el parámetro url y la verdad, que no encuentro el error!!!

```html
$urlweb = $_GET["urlweb"];
// DB Connection 
include('conn.php');

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE urlweb = '$urlweb' ORDER BY id DESC";
$statement = $connection->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
while($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
 $data[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

si cambio, urlweb = '$urlweb' por urlweb = 'yo', me arroja el resultado que le estoy pidiendo!!
ahora, si lo busco en ?url=yo no me devuelve nada!

PARA QUE SE ENTIENDA
Estoy armando una web, donde el parámetro urlweb es un usuario X y necesito que devuelva los datos de ese solo usuario!!

index.php?urlweb=yo

Comment: Estas sobreescribiendo tu variable data en cada iteracion,  cuando lo haces el valor anterior por supuesto es reemplazado con el nuevo,  pero NO se añaden elementos,  para eso debes usar array_push de php, ademas de que creo que estas algo confundido sobre el como funciona una peticion GET...

Comment: Si estas recibiendo urlweb a manera de extraer los datos por medio de una URL contenida dentro de urlweb entonces estas haciendolo mal, los datos que se envian por GET son recibidos de manera diferente... no deberian ser recibidos como una URL completa que envias...